# SQL Server: "Mostly-unique" index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, unique-constraint, multiple-columns

In a table i want to ensure that only unique vales exist over the five-column key:

```
Timestamp Account RatingDate TripHistoryKey EventAction
========= ======= ========== ============== ===========
2010511   1234    2010511    1              INSERT
2010511   1234    2010511    4              INSERT
2010511   1234    2010511    7              INSERT
2010511   1234    2010511    1              INSERT   <---duplicate
```

**But** i only want the unique constraint to apply between rows when **EventAction** is `INSERT`:

```
Timestamp Account RatingDate TripHistoryKey EventAction
========= ======= ========== ============== ===========
2010511   1234    2010511    1              INSERT
2010511   1234    2010511    1              UPDATE
2010511   1234    2010511    1              UPDATE   <---not duplicate
2010511   1234    2010511    1              UPDATE   <---not duplicate
2010511   1234    2010511    1              DELETE   <---not duplicate
2010511   1234    2010511    1              DELETE   <---not duplicate
2010511   1234    2010511    1              INSERT   <---DUPLICATE
```

Possible?

Comment: What is event Action? I suspect that you have a design issue and that you may want to consider creating a table/relation for each type of EventAction. Perhaps you can provide the business context to your question.

Comment: The table represents an audit log trail of another table (Insert, update, delete). i don't want duplicate "insert" operations making it into my table. (The contents of this table are generated by a different database product, on a different server, and i am dumped a copy of a copy of the audit trail, for the privilege of trying to parse it).  i could also change the column names to **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**, and **E**, and replace column values with numbers - if that helps to get at the core question.

Answer (score 5):

Yes

- SQL Server 2008: use a filtered index
- SQL Server 2005: use a trigger or indexed view

Edit:

- [Indexed view example](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/17/60209.aspx)

Comment: Any suggestions on a trigger, or non-schema bound view syntax that would accomplish the goal?

Comment: @Ian Boyd: you'll have to use a trigger if you can't SCHEMABIND a view for indexing

Comment: Any suggestions for the syntax of the trigger?

Answer (score 2):

What is an EventAction?

I suspect that you have a design issue at work here and that you may want to consider creating a table/relation for each type of EventAction. Doing so would enable you to create a unique constraint on the InsertEventAction table for example.

Perhaps you can provide the business context to your question.

**Following on from comments reply:** Given the nature of the data source and the parsing activity you wish to implement I think gbn has suggested your best options.

It's a shame the source database is not also SQL Server as you could implement your own audit mechanism using Triggers. Such a solution could include your "filter" logic within the Trigger.

Comment: Responded to comment in comment section.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider doing this with a check constraint. I don't think a traditional unique constraint will work.

Comment: Any suggestions on a check constraint syntax that would accomplish the goal?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of an "INSTEAD OF INSERT" trigger. The EXISTS checks if there are existing rows with the same values, but only when EventAction is INSERT.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[YourTriggerName] ON [dbo].[YourTableName] 
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [YourTableName] L
    INNER JOIN inserted I ON
           I.Timestamp = L.Timestamp
       AND I.Account = L.Account
       AND I.RatingDate = L.RatingDate
       AND I.TripHistoryKey = L.TripHistoryKey
       AND I.EventAction = 'INSERT'
  )
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO [YourTableName]
      SELECT * FROM inserted
  END
END
```